# Image resizing while using text area inside an html div

Tags: css

I have a rich text area field that stores image. This image is to be embedded in a div of fixed col size. However i am unable to resize the image and restrict it from overflowing out of the div. which tag can help me in achieving that

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting overflow css property of div to hidden.

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

You can also take help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265135/displaying-image-of-unknown-size-inside-div-of-fixed-size) post.

Comment: That helped .But the image is not dynamically resizing for smaller window sizes.